# select all data from table where value = something

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
map1
```

with columns

```
cham1 , cham2 , cham3 , cham4 , cham5 , cham6 , cham7 , cham8 , cham9
```

Some columns have a value of 100, and some have a value of 200

I want to select the columns with the value 100 or value 200

The SQL query should be like this:

```
select cham1,cham2,cham3,cham4,cham5 from map1 where value of  = 100 ;
```

i want the to select the column that have the value 100 from table column

Comment: Please share the queries you have tried and explain what didn't work.

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM map1 WHERE 100 IN (cham1,cham2,cham3,cham4,cham5)` maybe?

Comment: i want the to select the column that have the value 100 from table column

Comment: Numbered column names suggests a prime candidate for further normalisation

Comment: @AhmedSafadi you said, "I want to select the columns with the **value 100 or value 200**".

Comment: I can see OP's ***"GONE FISHING"*** sign posted up.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM map1
WHERE cham1 IN (100, 200)
  OR cham2 IN (100, 200)
  OR cham3 IN (100, 200)
  OR cham4 IN (100, 200)
  OR cham5 IN (100, 200)
;
```

This query sounds like you store in 5 columns (`cham1`..`cham5`) values that should be stored in a single column. Or, most probably, they need to stay (in the same column) in a separate table.

Comment: i want the to select the column that have the value 100 from table column

Comment: Please update the question and put a clear example of what you have in the table (several rows) and what you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
SELECT *
FROM `map1`
WHERE `cham1` IN (100, 200)
OR `cham2` IN (100, 200)
OR `cham3` IN (100, 200)
OR `cham4` IN (100, 200)
OR `cham5` IN (100, 200)
```

Comment: Yeah, just as you said in comments. Then OP needs to use something like `WHERE col1=100 OR col2=100 OR col1=200 OR col2=200` etc. etc. etc. but I could be wrong about this one. Question is a tad unclear.

Comment: Looks like this one's *dead in the water*. Oh well, at least the fish enjoyed the worms.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "want to select column"? Column name? or the value of that column?

This will give comma separated column names that have 100 or 200

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT(
      CASE WHEN cham1 IN (100,200) THEN 'cham1,' ELSE '' END, 
      CASE WHEN cham2 IN (100,200) THEN 'cham2,' ELSE '' END, 
            . . . 
      CASE WHEN cham5 IN (100,200) THEN 'cham5,' ELSE '' END
) FROM MAP1
```

This will select only 100s and 200s

```
SELECT 
      cham1 = CASE WHEN cham1 IN (100,200) THEN cham1 ELSE NULL END, 
      cham2 = CASE WHEN cham2 IN (100,200) THEN cham2 ELSE NULL END, 
            . . . 
      cham5 = CASE WHEN cham5 IN (100,200) THEN cham5 ELSE NULL END
FROM MAP1
```

And if you want to limit rows only those having 100 or 200 you can add `where` clause

```
WHERE cham1 IN (100, 200)
OR cham2 IN (100, 200)
OR cham3 IN (100, 200)
OR cham4 IN (100, 200)
OR cham5 IN (100, 200)
```